# Cache data locally from a slow recource

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching

I'm developing a C#.net App.
My app needs to get a list from a very slow API, do some work on it, and present it to the user. Fortunately, this list doesn't change much often and I can manage a 10 minutes delay. Therefore, I want to cache it.

What I tried:
I Used System.Cache to cache that list for 10 minutes , and used a remove callback to cache it again every 10 minutes. This only works if a user has a session with the server!! Whenever no one is using the website, the cache is gone and the next user entering will experience the slowness!!

This is the code I used:

```
public void RemovedCallback(String k, Object v, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
{
    List<string> list = getListFromSlowAPI();
    Cache.Insert("TheList", list, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10), TimeSpan.Zero, CacheItemPriority,Default, new CacheItemRenovedCallback(this.RemovedCallback));
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Cache["TheList"] == null)
    {
        RemovedCallback("", null, new CacheItemRemovedReason());        
    }

    List<string> list = (List<string>)Cache["TheList"];

    // do stuff with list   
}
```

I need a way to cache the list every 10 minutes forever regardless of user activity.

Thanks :)

Comment: Is it a website app? If yes please update your tags

Comment: Assuming ASP.Net: " if a user has a session" ? That remark makes no sense as caching information in ASP.Net cache should not be dependent on user... You either trying to cache user specific data globally OR code that fetches shared data incorrectly tries to access session/request. Without actual code it is hard to say what is wrong there.

Comment: How long does it take to fetch the new list from the slow api?

Comment: I found a really good article about the subject: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/caching-data/caching-data-at-application-startup-cs
It helped me find the solution...
Since my calling to the callback came from the pageload of a specific page - when the session with the page died- the callbacks did to.
But! if i put it on "Application_Start" in Global.asax it works :) :)

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to fake a scheduler to refresh the cache by using the Page_Load on ASP.Net WebForms. I suggest you figure out how to correctly schedule recurrent tasks in ASP.Net. Which depends on which version of IIS you are running in.